# Qgis crash with maptool plugin

Tags: qgis-plugins

I have a qgis plugin (c++) that adds a map tool inherits from QgsMapTool. My tool does nothing, juste I can activate my tool by triggering.
I test my plugin in Qgis 2.4; when I activate my tool the I passed to another tool Qgis crash and write a minimum dump file.

Dump File: qgis-20140915-111427-2760-1564-8fdd08a.dmp : C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\qgis-20140915-111427-2760-1564-8fdd08a.dmp
Last Write Time: 15/09/2014 11:14:28
Process Name: qgis-bin.exe : C:\Program Files (x86)\QGIS Chugiak\bin\qgis-bin.exe
Process Architecture: x86
Exception Code: 0xC0000005
Exception Information: The thread tried to read from or write to a virtual address for which it does not have the appropriate access.
Heap Information: Not Present

### System Information

OS Version: 6.1.7601
CLR Version(s):

### Modules

Module Name Module Path Module Version

---

qgis-bin.exe C:\Program Files (x86)\QGIS Chugiak\bin\qgis-bin.exe 0.0.0.0
ntdll.dll C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll 6.1.7601.18247
....

this is the C++ code:

```
MapToolAdvancedEditPolygons::MapToolAdvancedEditPolygons( QgisInterface *ptInterface )
    : QgsMapTool( ptInterface->mapCanvas () )
    , m_ptInterface ( ptInterface )
{
}

MapToolAdvancedEditPolygons::~MapToolAdvancedEditPolygons()
{
}
```

I initialised my plugin as below:

```
void GeoAdvancedEditTool::initGui ()
{
 m_ptAdvancedEditAction = new QAction ( QIcon ( ":/geoadvancededittool/images/AdvancedEditAction.png" ), tr ( "advanced edit polygons tool" ), this);
 m_ptAdvancedEditAction->setCheckable ( true );
 m_ptAdvancedEditAction->setActionGroup ( m_ptInterface->actionMoveFeature()->actionGroup() );
 m_ptInterface->digitizeToolBar()->addAction ( m_ptAdvancedEditAction );

 connect( m_ptAdvancedEditAction, SIGNAL( triggered() ), this, SLOT( advancedEditActivated() ) );

 m_ptMapToolAdvancedEditPolygons = new MapToolAdvancedEditPolygons( m_ptInterface );
 m_ptMapToolAdvancedEditPolygons->setObjectName( "GEOAdvancedEditPolygonsTool" );
 m_ptMapToolAdvancedEditPolygons->setAction( m_ptAdvancedEditAction );
 m_ptAdvancedEditAction->setEnabled(true);
}

void GeoAdvancedEditTool::advancedEditActivated()
{
 m_ptInterface->mapCanvas()->setMapTool( m_ptMapToolAdvancedEditPolygons );
 m_ptInterface->mapCanvas()->setCursor( QCursor( Qt::CrossCursor ) );
}
```

I don't understand why Qgis crash!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Problem solved, I must use Qgis libraries shipped with OSGeo4W.